# Table styling in Rpresentation

Tags: r

I would like to have nice tables in my RPres(entation). If I use the `kableExtra`package I can produce nice tables in the RStudio Viewer Pane like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

frame_data(
    ~column1, ~column2
    , 1, 2
    , 3, 4) %>%
kable("html") %>%
kable_styling()
```

but if I knit the presentation nothing happens. It's just as if I simply used the "simple" kable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to have a look at the [xaringan](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan) presentation.

````
# Create table

```{r tidy=FALSE, eval=TRUE}

library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)
tribble(
    ~column1, ~column2
    , 1, 2
    , 3, 4) %>%
kable("html") %>%
kable_styling()
```
````

-output slide

[image]

---

In the Rpresentation, the slide generator code is

````
Slide With Code
========================================================

```{r, eval = TRUE}
library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

tribble(
    ~column1, ~column2
    , 1, 2
    , 3, 4) %>%
kable("html") %>%
kable_styling()
```
````

-output slide

[image]

Comment: Why may it be better? Is there something wrong the rpres? I really like the rpres since it easily goes into fullscreen mode.

Comment: @Georgery There is not much wrong with rpres, but it is having much more control in the output from what I understand

Comment: OK, but is there a way to use it in rpres?

Comment: @Georgery  I did some presentations with Rpres in the past, but I had a lot of issues with controlling the placement of figures etc.  With axarigan, it seems easier.  Can you try it

Comment: @Georgery  It is working for me in Rpresentation.  Open the file in browser.  Updated the post\